# Object not set to a reference of an object

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
 String LineNo;
 LineNo = txtLineNumber.Value.ToString();
```

It is giving me the titled error message.

Thanks

Comment: The Value would be null, try using .Text

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Either txtLineNumber does not exist or txtLineNumber.Value is null;